# Magento 2: Get custom editor attribute by category id for category on frontend

Tags: magento2

I am not able to get custom editor attribute by category id.

Here is my code:

```
$categoryData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($collection);
 $swatch_attribute = $categoryData->getData('swatch_icons');
```

I am not getting the result with this code.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Object Manager is not good way so you make the this type may be help you

**code/Mage/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Cool',
    __DIR__
);
```

**code/Mage/Cool/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mage_Cool" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**code/Mage/Cool/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Mage\Cool\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;    
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'cat_infotab',
        [

            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Category Info Tab',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 333,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
            'group' => 'General Information' 

        ]
    );

   $setup->endSetup(); 
}
}
```

**code/Mage/Cool/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">    
<fieldset name="content">
     <field name="cat_infotab">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Info Tab</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">250px</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">cat_infotab</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>          
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**code/Mage/Cool/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description.bottom" template="Mage_Cool::product/list.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**code/Mage/Cool/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

```
<?php if ($_bottomDescription = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getCatInfotab()): ?>
    <div class="category-bottom-description">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_bottomDescription, 'cat_infotab') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get your custom attribute below way.

```
$catId = 5; // category id 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$PCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($catId);
echo $PCategory->getCustomAttribute(); // here get your attribute
// OR
$PCategory->getData('custom_attribute');
```